# Вызов функции во фрагменте только один раз

Tags: android

Во фрагменте, внутри onViewCreated вызывается функция
new DownloadJSON().execute()
Сейчас он выполняется каждый раз при вызове фрагмента.

Как сделать чтобы new DownloadJSON().execute() выполнялся только один раз?

Comment: Каким образом вы создаете фрагмент? Почему этот метод дергается по нескольку раз? Как вариант попробуйте этот метод запихнуть в метод onCreate или onAttach

Comment: C помощью классов SlidingTabLayout и SlidingTabStrip созданы вкладки с фрагменты: 
        case 0:
            fragment = new ScreenOne();
            break;
 case 1:
            fragment = new Akcii();
            break;

Comment: лучше сделайте синглтоны фрагментов

Answer (score 1):

Если ты используешь `Viewpager`, то:

```
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(6); //здесь установи количество фрагментов
```

Или:
Покажи код мне